# ASP.NET Core application published to IIS doesn't return error 500 description

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, iis-8, http-status-code-500

So I have this ASP.NET Core app deployed to IIS. When an exception occurs, I get an "500 Internal server error". And I know the actual error description is saved somewhere in the server. However, I want the app to return the error description just like when I debug from Visual Studio with IISExpress.

Even if I try the app locally (from the server), it would only return the "500 Internal server error" without description.

This is all I've tried:

- Deploying the app in debug mode.
- Adding `<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough"/>` to the `system.webServer` section in `web.config`
- Adding `<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"/>` to the `system.webServer` section in `web.config`
- Adding `<customErrors mode="Off />` to the `system.web` section in  `web.config`.
- From IIS Error Pages settings: setting the error responses as **Detailed** errors.
- From IIS Net Error Pages settings: setting the Mode to **Off**.

Not sure what else to do. I've been banging my head against the keyboard for several hours.

Thanks!

Comment: if you publish self-contained you might try this in program.cs: Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT", "Development");  If displaying from ajax call, use XHR.responseText on your .fail() or .error() callback.

Comment: What is your configuration when publishing? Where do you get the 500 error?

Comment: @pcalkins that is the correct answer, in case you want to answer, I'll mark that as the correct answer.